# ¿Como realizar una serie de permutaciones en python con una lista y un set?

Tags: python

disculpen alguien sabe como podria hacer permutaciones en python con una lista definida y ciertos numeros, les explico:

tengo una lista, con ciertos items

```
lista = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
```

despues tengo un set con ciertos numeros:

```
set = {3,4,5}
```

lo que quiero realizar, es una lista de permutaciones con los numeros contenidos en el set, que cada item de la lista se sustituya con los numeros conenidos en el set de la siguiente manera:

```
[3,4,3,5,4]
[3,5,3,4,4]
[3,4,4,3,4]
[5,4,5,5,4]
[4,4,5,5,5]
....
```

y asi sucesivamente,

Si alguien ha intentado hacer esto y pudieran compartirme la manera de aplicar el algoritmo, se los agradeceria.

Saludos

Comment: ¿qué relación hay entre las letras de la lista y los números del set? ¿por qué el 3 aparece dos veces en los primeros casos, y luego en cambio deja de aparecer? ¿Se trata de asignar al azar las letras de la lista a números del set? Pero entonces eso no serían permutaciones. Básicamente se trataría de construir listas de 5 elementos, tomando los elementos del set(), con reposición (es decir, que el elemento se devuelve al conjunto y puede ser extraido luego)

Comment: No tienen relacion las letras, es una lista de 5 posiciones, o si lo quieres ver de otra manera, una lista vacia, pero con 5 casillas a las cuales necesitaria todas las combinaciones posibles con los numeros contenidos en el set

Comment: Entendido. Pues mira a ver si te sirve mi respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Lo que solicitas no son permutaciones, ya que en las permutaciones lo que tendrías son siempre los mismos 5 elementos (digamos los números 3,3,4,4,5) reordenados de todas las formas posibles, pero siempre dos treses, dos cuatros y un cinco.

En cambio a juzgar por tu ejemplo, lo que buscas es sencillamente que el primer elemento de la lista se rellene con una cifra a elegir entre (3,4,5), el segundo elemento lo mismo, el tercero igual, etc... Así podrías obtener por ejemplo como resultado `[3, 3, 3, 3, 3]` pero también `[3, 3, 3, 3, 4]`, etc.

No me queda claro si quieres ir obteniendo estos elementos "al azar" (en cuyo caso bastaría con ir eligiendo una cifra al azar entre (3,4,5) para cada posición de la lista) o realmente quieres **todas** las combinaciones posibles.

### Obtener casos al azar

```
import random
def dame_un_caso(conjunto, n=5):
  lista = []
  for _ in range(n):
    lista.append(random.choice(list(conjunto)))
  return lista
```

Cada vez que llames a `dame_un_caso(conjunto)` te devolverá una lista de 5 elementos elegidos al azar dentro del conjunto. Por ejemplo:

```
>>> dame_un_caso({3,4,5})
[3, 5, 4, 4, 5]
```

### Obtener todos los casos

El número de combinaciones en este caso no es muy elevado, pero dependiendo del tamaño del conjunto y de la lista sí puede serlo. Si `N` es el tamaño de la lista y `M` es el tamaño del conjunto, el número de combinaciones sería de M**N (pues tienes M posibles elecciones para el primer elemento y por cada una de ellas otras M para el segundo, etc. con lo que al final tienes `M*M*M*...*M` repetido N veces).

En tu caso N=5, M=3 sale 3**5 que son 241 combinaciones.

Si las quieres todas, la operación que en realidad necesitas es el producto cartesiano del conjunto (3,4,5) por sí mismo, 5 veces. Esta operación te la hace `itertools.product`, así:

```
from itertools import product
l = list(product({3,4,5}, repeat=5))
```

Si miras `len(l)` verás 241, lo que coincide con lo esperado. Si muestras los elementos de `l` encontrarás (en este orden):

```
[(3, 3, 3, 3, 3),
 (3, 3, 3, 3, 4),
 (3, 3, 3, 3, 5),
 (3, 3, 3, 4, 3),
 (3, 3, 3, 4, 4),
 (3, 3, 3, 4, 5),
 (3, 3, 3, 5, 3),
 (3, 3, 3, 5, 4),
 (3, 3, 3, 5, 5),
 (3, 3, 4, 3, 3),
 (3, 3, 4, 3, 4),
 (3, 3, 4, 3, 5),

... etc
```

Comment: Amigo me ayudaste con tu respuesta, eres un crack, muchas gracias

Comment: Buena respuesta +1